# Add values to an array, print all values, and the sum of all values in an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, while-loop

I want to create a loop that asks for a price and then stores that price in a new object of an array every time the iteration occurs.

```
double itemPrice = 0;
double totalPrice = 0;
const double OVER_FIFTY_DISCOUNT = .1;
double priceSentinal = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Please input the price of your item. Enter '0' if you have no more items.");
itemPrice = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

while (itemPrice != priceSentinal) 
{

    Console.WriteLine("Please input the price of your item.");
    itemPrice = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    double[] originalPrices = itemPrice.ToDoubleArray();

    if (itemPrice >= 50)
    {
        itemPrice = itemPrice * OVER_FIFTY_DISCOUNT;
    }

    totalPrice = totalPrice + itemPrice;
    double[] allPrices = itemPrice.ToDoubleArray();  // how do I place every iteration of itemPrice
    Console.WriteLine("Your total Price is " + totalPrice); //into a new array value?
}

//How do I print every object in an array onto the screen?
//How do I add all of the objects within an array together and print them onto the screen?

Console.WriteLine("The prices of your items before discounts are " + originalPrices[]);
Console.WriteLine("The total price of your items before discounts is " originalPrices[]);
Console.WriteLine("The prices of your items after discounts are " + allPrices[]);
Console.WriteLine("The total price of your items after discounts is " + allPrices[]);
```

I don't know how to add a new object to a double array for every iteration of the loop. I also don't know how to print every object within an array on to the screen, and I also don't know how to add all of the objects in an array and print them onto the screen. Could someone help me fix my code please?

Comment: instead of using an array use ArrayList<int>

Comment: There is even bigger question: why to use an array at all if a single var type of double used as an accumulator plus another int var used as counter can do the job. Best regards,

Comment: _ArrayList_??? No, it is pretty much deprecated. Use a List<int> or a  List<decimal> !

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**: this is a little long-winded, but hopefully you will read through it all and learn something. There are a lot of tools at your disposal to complete these tasks, but starting with the basics is probably the best. (Hint: make sure you check out the links, they are quite helpful)

There are a couple of things here that you will want to look into and learn how to use.

First, you will want to look into [Lists](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list).

## Lists

Lists are array-like data structures that you can *dynamically* add values to. An example of using a list is like this:

```
// Create a new list that can hold integers
List<int> listOfInts = new List<int>();

// Add values to the list
listOfInts.Add(1);
listOfInts.Add(2);
```

Second, you will want to look into [`for`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/for) and [`foreach`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/foreach) loops.

## Loops

Like the [`while`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/while) loop, the [`for`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/for) and [`foreach`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/foreach) loops allow you to repeat code. However, unlike the [`while`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/while), the [`for`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/for) and [`foreach`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/foreach) loops allow you to repeat over a certain set of values. This allows you to easily build strings by repeating the string concatenation code over your values:

Given our code above, we can create a string that contains each of the numbers like this:

```
string numbersString = "";
foreach(int number in listOfInts)
{
    numbersString += number.ToString() + " ";
}
```

(Sidenote)

Now, the code above is not exactly best practice for building strings, but it demonstrates how you would use a [`foreach`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/foreach) on a collection of values. (Check out the [`String.Join`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-join) method for an easy way of building strings from lists/arrays)

(End Sidenote)

So, combining the two ideas of lists and loops, you can calculate a sum like this:

```
int sum = 0;
foreach(int number in listOfInts)
{
   sum += number;
}
// sum == 3
```

(2nd Sidenote)

Again, the code above is probably not what you would write yourself. More commonly, you would use a [LINQ](http://www.dotnetperls.com/linq) extension method like [`Sum()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534734%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to calculate the sum of the values in a collection.

(End 2nd Sidenote)

So, to answer you question,

> Add values to an array, print all values, and the sum of all values in an array in C#

Use a [list](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list) for the values:

```
List<double> values = new List<double>();

// inside a loop somewhere
values.Add(aValue);
```

Print all of the values by either:

1. Using a loop and `Console.Write()`:

   ```
   foreach(double value in values)
   {
       Console.Write("{0} ", value);
   }
   ```
2. Using a loop to add values to a `string` and then `Console.WriteLine()`:

   ```
   string finalString = "";
   foreach(double value in values)
   {
       finalString += value.ToString() + " ";
   }
   ```
3. Using [`String.Join()`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-join):

   ```
   Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", values));
   ```

Use either, it's your choice.

And finally, Sum all of the values using either:

1. A loop and sum variable (See the sum example)
2. The [`Sum()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534734%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension method:

   ```
   using System.Linq;
   //...
   double sum = values.Sum();
   ```

Comment: Thank you. I would vote you up, but I'm still a noob. Your advice was  very helpful. I didn't even know what lists were. I'm still taking logic and design.